# Why is my java EXTENDS not working?

Tags: java, extends

I hava a Super Class Ball with extender OvalBall. With following being my code I am getting a error message telling me I can't use the child class OvalBall. can anyone help explain please?

```
public class Ball                                       
{
  private double diameter;
  private String colour;

  public Ball(double d, String c)
  {
    this.diameter = d;
    this.colour = c;
  }

  public void setDiameter(double d)
  {
    this.diameter = d;
  }

  public double getDiameter()
  {
    return this.diameter;
  }

  public void setColour(String c)
  {
    this.colour = c;
  }

  public String getColour()
  {
    return colour;
  }

  public double bounce()
  {
    double height = diameter * 2;
    return height;
  }

  public void roll()
  {
    System.out.println("wheeee");
  }


  public class OvalBall extends Ball
  {
    private double secondDiameter;



    public void setSecondDiameter(double sd)
    {
      this.secondDiameter = sd;

    }

    public double getSecondDiameter()
    {
      return this.secondDiameter;

    }
  }

} 

public class Main                                       
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
   OvalBall na = new OvalBall(4,"blue",4);
    na.setSDiameter(10);
    System.out.println(na.bounce());
  }
}
```

Feel free to change anything.

Thanks

Comment: Is OvalBall an inner class (or nested class whatever Java's terminology is) ? Not sure if I'm seeing that correctly. If so, then Ball.OverBall but that.. -_-

Comment: Always show the *exact* error message, and be specific about where you're getting it.

Comment: As it stands, I don't think your code will compile - so your statement "I am getting a error message telling me I can't use the child class OvalBall." is confusing - see @JonSkeet comment above - be very specific about the error message, where and *when* you're seeing it (compile time or run time)

Answer (score 0):

You need to define `OvalBall` either as `static` or in its own file.

Comment: No, we don't have to (even if it makes sense in this case). Other option is adding proper constructor and creating instance of inner OvalBall class from outer class Ball instance.

Comment: You wouldn't declare `OvalBall` static as the OP is clearly indicating they want to instantiate it.  You may well be right that the intent is to extend in a conventional way and have `OvalBall` in a separate file, but we haven't enough info to know that.  @Pshemo is right - it's legal to have inner class extend outer and we could use that with the correct constructor added and operating on an instance of the outer class (`Ball`)

Answer (score -1):

Maybe OvalBall din't implement the constructor class of hi base class
That's why you can't create a object of OvalBall.

```
class Ball {//This is you base class contructor

//Child class contructor
public class OvalBall extends Ball
{
   public OvalBall(double d, String c)
  {
   base(d,c);
  }
}
```

And when you make nested classes in java there is a different. way to create an object instance instead of other languages Like C#.
Try in this way. [or use my code as example](https://github.com/MrAlex6204/java-game-mundial/blob/master/src/mundial/Mundial.java)

```
public class Main                                       
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
   Ball.OvalBall na = na.new OvalBall(4,"blue",4);
    na.setSDiameter(10);
    System.out.println(na.bounce());
  }
}
```